# macOS Catalina still uses bash as the default shell

Tags: terminal, bash, zsh

I'm on the latest public beta of macOS Catalina and it's supposed to use `zsh` as the default shell and it even shows that it is pointing to `zsh` in the users settings but whenever I open a new terminal window it says:

[image]

and even when I run that specified command, it says: **no changes made**

What do I do?

Comment: I upgraded to Catalina from Mojave.  I expect that the default shell is still Bash because of the upgrade.  It's not a fresh install.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out the terminal app has its own settings for which shell to use.
I had to go to terminal preferences and change the option for `Shells open with` to `Default login shell`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Run your `chsh` command with `sudo` to make changes effective system-wide.**

To change your default shell setting by using the shell,

You can first view the `/etc/shells` file to note the available shells and their paths on your system.

You can run `chsh` interactively (i.e. without any arguments) or with the `-s` or `--shell` flag, followed by the shell path.

Answer (score -1):

New user accounts will be created with zsh as the default shell. Existing accounts will keep whatever settings they already have in place.

Comment: True, but not sure how this answers the question. The OP tried to change shells apparently, but it didn't work as expected.